# Setup port 8443 on Tomcat errors while using tomcat monitor

Tags: https, tomcat9

I try to setup port 8443 for https on Tomcat 9.0.54.
For this I followed the following instructions :

I first created a key store:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

Then I updated my server.xml file

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true"
       acceptCount="100" 
       clientAuth="false" 
       disableUploadTimeout="true" 
       enableLookups="false" 
       maxThreads="25" 
       port="8443" 
       keystoreFile="C:/Users/Me/.keystore" 
       keystorePass="changeit" 
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
       scheme="https" 
       secure="true" 
       sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

So far so good. I launch startup.bat and I do have my server running startup.bat command. My issue is that my server must be launched at server startup if this one must be restarted. For this I set a service that launch automatically tomcat at startup.

[image]

At this stage, my servers starts and http://localhost:8080/ redirects to https://localhost:8443/.
I can reach my manager page on 8080 (http://localhost:8080/manager/html) and fails on 8443(can't open the page on https://localhost:8443/manager/html)

Comment: There is certainly a permission problem: the keystore is probably accessible only by user `Me`, whereas Tomcat runs as `LocalService` unless you changed it (see the _"Log On"_ tab).

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy ! I moved my keystore to the following path : C:/server/.keystore and changed path in server.xml !!! thanks !!!